# Getting code=10053 error while installing groovy-eclipse on Eclipse IDE (Oxygen) for Eclipse Committers

Tags: groovy-eclipse

After following the steps in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-with-Groovy-Eclipse-Source-Code.md (on macOS High Sierra) getting an error:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10053 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Software being installed: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1527811536694
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Missing requirement: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1527811536694 requires 'org.codehaus.groovy.alltests.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I am not sure why org.codehaus.groovy.alltests is not found and whether the version 0.0.0 is legit here.
I tried to make a clean installation too (deleted ~/.gradle, ~/.p2 dirs) - did not help.

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.alltests is a feature provided by the Groovy-Eclipse update site.  For Eclipse Oxygen, the linked update site is a snapshot site (updated per CI build), so you may have caught it mid-deploy.  Is the error still occurring if you try the steps again?

Comment: yeah, same error today

Comment: Just tried to do the same on PC - same error. So it is not just a mac-specific issue. Note I've been using anonymous github url for the groovy-eclipse source (https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse.git)

Comment: I see the issue with the Oomph setup.  Could you submit this as an issue to the github site and we can continue resolution there?

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/592

Comment: Your fix looks good, I was able to set it up and build. Created an issue and PR on a DSLD bug, could you please take a look?